# Django views/templates: list filtering based on a current a site category

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-filters

In my app user can create and manage `organizations` -> `projects` -> `resources` and so on. A `project` instance has a FK to `organization`, `resource` has a FK to `project`.

In example, when user selects an active organization, i want `projects` view to display only projects that belong to this organization. I see these ways:

**Optional argument in all specific urls**:

```
url(r'^(?:organization/(?P<organization_id>\d+)/)?projects/$', 'app.views.projects', name='projects'),
url(r'^(?:organization/(?P<organization_id>\d+)/)?(?:project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/)?resources/$', 'app.views.resources', name='resources'),
```

Also, this method forces to rewrite all `{% url %}` tags in templates:

```
`{% url 'projects' org.id %}` 
`{% url 'resources' org.id  prj.id %}`
```

but that's all does not look pretty, especially `urls.py`.

#### UPDATE 1

This method forces to pass `organization_id` in templates *everytime*. Even if I write middleware to avoid annoying passing it in context,

```
class FetchFiltersMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        request.project_id = view_kwargs.get('project_id', 0)
        request.organization_id = view_kwargs.get('organization_id', 0)
```

anyway, **ALL** site urls must be rewritten to contain `organization_id`, otherwise filtering will be broken. Even if it's not necessary, i.e. in user profile view all sidebar links to `projects` will be broken.

**Storing a current filter in cookie or GET argument**

like `{% url 'myurl' %}&project={{ project_id }}`. bad. ugly.

**Storing a last selected `organization`/`project` id in cache or session**

Easy to use. But not userside-explicit. Also it will generate problems when site opened in multiple tabs with different organizations selected on each tab.

At this moment i see first way looks better, but a lot of rewrite work is required. Is there a better way to do category/section based filtering?

#### UPDATE 2

If it's not clean yet. The selection of the project, or organization - it's actually switching the current display context. In the context of the selected organization all links should lead to projects in this organization, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer the first way. If you have a relatively simple structure, you can simplify  your template by using `get_absolute_url`. For example, `{{ org.get_absolute_url }}` could lead to the `projects` view, `{{ prj.get_absolute_url }}` to resources etc.

In an older project, I used the session-way, and still regret it, exactly because of the problems with multiple tabs/windows. Using a cookie has the same problems. I think the "ugliness" of the URL configuration in the first way is worth the gain in usability.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Also, what do you think about replacing `{% url view %}` tags with `{{ model_instance.absolute_url }}` everywhere it's possible?

Comment: If it improves readability, go for it. It also helps for future url changes, for example, if you had the project - resource connection, and you are adding the origanization, you wouldn't have to change the templates if they are using `get_absolute_url`, only the method on the model.